# Error: Class 'Stripe' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, bolt-cms

I'm trying to use the Stripe php api in a Bolt extension but it's having trouble finding the class. I added the Stripe library to `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "stripe/stripe-php": "1.*"
}
```

And ran `composer install`. `myextension/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` now shows the classes loaded:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));

return array(
    'Stripe' => $vendorDir . '/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe/Stripe.php',
    'Stripe_Account' => $vendorDir . '/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe/Account.php',
    'Stripe_ApiConnectionError' => $vendorDir . '/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe/ApiConnectionError.php',
    'Stripe_ApiError' => $vendorDir . '/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe/ApiError.php',
    ...
```

And now I'm trying to use it in the extension like this:

```
use Stripe, Stripe_Customer, Stripe_Charge, Stripe_Plan, Stripe_Coupon, Stripe_Error;

public function initialize()
{
    $stripe = new Stripe();
    $stripe->setApiKey($this->config['stripe_key']);
```

But I get the error:

> Error: Class 'Stripe' not found
>       File: extensions/local/andyjessop/myextension/Extension.php

I still haven't got my head round autoloading, so I think I'm doing something basic wrong, but I can't see what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you include the autoload.php in your script?

Comment: Does Bolt include the autoload.php file for you? You might need to include it yourself if it doesn't.

Comment: Post the github of your project, so we can see how everything connects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the composer autoload file.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: But only once in the bootstrapping, not in every file!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this command

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

also make sure you are updating your composer file, this will work cheers